# Convert CSV file to SAS Table (sas7bdat)

Tags: r, sas, converters

I have a huge CSV file, and i want to convert it to a SAS Table.
 I know that i can use SAS to make an import, but i am interested in creating the SAS table using, for example: C++, python or any available library.

For example, in SPSS I can easily create a SAS Table using the command "Save as type" to SAS v9+ Windows (*.sas7bdat).
And it not necessary to have SAS installed.

I know that sas7bdat.py exists but it is only for reading sas7bdat..

Comment: If you're using r (ie, the tag), you should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476826/can-anyone-help-me-write-a-r-data-frame-as-a-sas-data-set .  SAS7BDAT is a closed format; in order to write to it you either have to license the details from them or reverse engineer the format, as a few people have done but I don't believe any open-source writers.  Reading is easier than writing (as a few open source readers do exist).

Comment: Does that completely answer your question (ie, can we close as a duplicate of the linked question) or do you still have further questions (or are you not using R)?

Comment: @Joe Using R, i can just create a transport file. I still have to execute a import inside SAS, to create a table(sas7bdat). So my question is not already solved.

Comment: That would have to be done inside SAS, or by connecting to a SAS ODBC provider or something like that.  The linked question has explanation for the CSV method I believe which includes the creation automatically of a SAS input script.